# Nunit-Console Assemblies cannot be loaded

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, nunit

I have created a TestApplication solution with 4 projects - iOS application, iOS tests, Droid Application, Droid tests.

My tests run successfully when i try to run in iphone simulator and android phones. However when i downloaded the Nunit from Nunit website and tried to run it in console, I get

> Could not load file or assembly 'UnitTestiOS, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies

and the command I used is

For iOS

```
mono Desktop/NUnit-2.6.3/bin/nunit-console.exe TestApplication/TestApplication/UnitTestiOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/UnitTestiOS.exe
```

For Android

```
mono Desktop/NUnit-2.6.3/bin/nunit-console.exe TestApplication/TestApplication/UnitTestDroid/bin/Debug/UnitTestDroid.dll
```

I tried to run using nunit-x86 GUI and it runs fine.

Is my command alright? Am I using the right dll's/exe's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I suspected, I had given the wrong .exe

I had to go to UnitTestiOS.app/UnitTestiOS.exe. It runs fine now.

```
mono Desktop/NUnit-2.6.3/bin/nunit-console.exe TestApplication/TestApplication/UnitTestiOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/UnitTestiOS.app/UnitTestiOS.exe
```